# Change filenames to lowercase in Ubuntu in all subdirectories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, rename

I know it's been asked but what I've found has not worked out so far.
The closet I came is this : `rename -n 'y[A-Z]/[a-z]/' *`
which works for the current directory. I'm not too good at Linux terminal so what
should I add to this command to apply it to all of the files in all the sub-directories from which I am in, thanks!

Comment: This is closed as off topic, but it has the best answer I've found to this exact question. Where would this fit better, and does it exist there?

Comment: @AndrewLott unix.SE or superuser.com

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's one way using `find` and `tr`:

```
for i in $(find . -type f -name "*[A-Z]*"); do mv "$i" "$(echo $i | tr A-Z a-z)"; done
```

Edit; added: `-name "*[A-Z]*"`

This ensures that only files with capital letters are found. For example, if files with only lowercase letters are found and moved to the same file, `mv` will display the `are the same file` error.

Comment: I'm going to try this, but it was just brought to my attention that the require calls in the php files are upper and lowercase in a ton of files. Is there a way to turn off case sensitivity in Ubuntu?

Comment: No.  Unix filesystems are case sensitive, there is no setting to turn it off.  I suppose you could run your app from a FAT32 filesystem as a workaround, but if your source code has case bugs they will need to be fixed manually.

Comment: This does not work if the directory contains upper case characters; mv fails as the new destination does not exist

Comment: You should also add a warning that this *deletes* some files if they have the same name (e.g., `Foo` vs `FOO`). Ideally, it would issue a warning in this case.

Comment: Also, in order for this to work with spaces, it should be `IFS=$'\n' && for i in $(find . -type f -name "*[A-Z]*"); do echo "$i" "$(echo "$i" | tr A-Z a-z)"; done ; unset IFS`

Answer (score 10):

Perl has a locale-aware `lc()` function which might work better:

```
find . -type f | perl -n -e 'chomp; system("mv", $_, lc($_))'
```

Note that this script handles whitespace in filenames, but not newlines.  And there's no protection against collisions, if you have "ASDF.txt" and "asdf.txt" one is going to get clobbered.