# How to change filenames to lowercase?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to change all names of all files in specific directory to lowercases, using bash script. Moreover I don't want to change names of subdirectories, as it was proposed in [How to rename all folders and files to lowercase on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152514/how-to-rename-all-folders-and-files-to-lowercase-on-linux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for file in *; do
    [[ -f "$file" ]] && mv "$file" "${file,,}" 2>/dev/null
done
```

I'm not sure what version of bash introduced the `${var,,}` expansion.

Comment: The [release notes](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS) have it as item hh for version 4.0.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
for file in * ; do lower=$(echo $file | tr A-Z a-z) && [[ $lower != $file ]] && echo mv $file $lower ;done
```

It will echo the commands you need to run. Check them first, then you can remove the echo and run it again to do the actual moves

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
for i in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*[A-Z]*"); do mv "$i" "$(echo $i | tr A-Z a-z)"; done
```

**[1]** [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051871/change-filenames-to-lowercase-in-ubuntu-in-all-subdirectories)

Comment: This is not a safe way to iterate over files: if you find a filename with a space, the for loop will not treat it as a single word.